# Rust: Enum vs Impl Trait vs?

Tags: enums, rust, stack, traits, serde

I have a function that deserializes content from a UnixStream into concrete struct definitions. These structs can be one of a number of variants: I originally opted for an enum, but clippy helpfully pointed out that a variant like

```
pub enum EventResponse {
    Workspace(WorkspaceData), 
    Output(OutputData),
    Mode(ModeData),
}
```

Is inefficient if `WorkspaceData` is very large and has many more fields than the others. This increases the minimum size of each variant.

To get around this, in my deserialization fn I Box some of the variants:

```
pub enum EventResponse {
    Workspace(Box<WorkspaceData>),
    Output(OutputData),
    Mode(ModeData)
}
  pub fn receive_evt(&mut self) -> io::Result<event::EventResponse> {
        let (evt_type, payload_bytes) = self.decode_msg()?;
        let body = match evt_type.into() {
            Event::Workspace => {
                EventResponse::Workspace(Box::new(serde_json::from_slice::<event::WorkspaceData>(
                    &payload_bytes[..],
                )?))
            }
            Event::Output => EventResponse::Output(serde_json::from_slice::<event::OutputData>(
                &payload_bytes[..],
            )?),
            Event::Mode => EventResponse::Mode(serde_json::from_slice::<event::ModeData>(
                &payload_bytes[..],
            )?),
        };
        Ok(body)
    }
```

However, it would be nice if I didn't have to Box any of the variants. With the advent of `impl Trait` is there a way to do this now?

I really wanted somethign like:

```
 pub fn receive_evt_2<D: DeserializeOwned>(
        &mut self,
    ) -> io::Result<EventResp<impl DeserializeOwned>> {
        let (evt_type, payload_bytes) = self.decode_msg()?;
        let evt_type = evt_type.into();
        let body = match evt_type {
            Event::Workspace => serde_json::from_slice::<event::WorkspaceData>(&payload_bytes[..])?,
            Event::Output => serde_json::from_slice::<event::OutputData>(&payload_bytes[..])?,
            Event::Mode => serde_json::from_slice::<event::ModeData>(&payload_bytes[..])?,
        };
        Ok(EventResp { evt_type, body })
    }
```

But this returns an error like "Expected type WorkspaceData, found type OutputData".

What are my options?

Comment: but what is `DeserializeOwned` ?

Comment: `impl Trait` as a return type is an existential, concrete type. You don't need to name it explicitly, but it still can only be a single, fixed type (possibly depending on generic type parameters to the function).

Comment: "A type that implements `Trait` but isn't known until runtime" is `dyn Trait`, not `impl Trait`. You could perhaps define `EventResp` so that it contains a `dyn Trait` member, but then you would just have to return a `Box<EventResp>`. There's currently no way around boxing to return an unsized type; that would require a second stack or something ([see RFC #1909](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1909-unsized-rvalues.md)).

Comment: @Stargateur, `DeserializeOwned` is a trait from `serde`, I'm trying to say that the function is returning something which can be deserialized.

@trentcl thanks I suppose that's what I'm looking for, yes this is a duplicate of that other Q